# {filter(x),filter(y)} array literal error if filter(x) or filter(y) noresult

Tags: google-sheets

I have issue with google sheets formula.

Formula: `={filter(x);filter(y)}`

If `filter(x)` or `filter(y)` gives no result match there is array literal error.

The temporary solution is:

`={iferror(filter(x);B1000:P1000);iferror(filter(y);B1000:P1000)}`

But in this case if `filter(x)` gives empty result there is an empty row.
Is there any solution so that if there is no result for `filter(x)`, no empty row will be displayed at the beginning of the table?

Comment: In your first formula you are appending the arrays horizontally (with a comma) but in the  second formula you are appending the arrays vertically (with a semicolon). Which is correct?

Comment: there  is everywhere semicolon in original formula - thanks, post edited

Answer (score 0):

As you are stacking arrays vertically you can try something like:

```
=tocol({filter(x);filter(y)};2)
```

The parameter 2 passed to the *Ignore* argument of TOCOL makes it skip any errors it finds, such as the #N/A error generated if either/both of your filters have no matches.

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to avoid creating an empty row, but then you can delete them in a further step.

As a prior suggestion, instead of using B1000:P1000 you can use WRAPROWS with empty values, being 15 the number of columns you need:

```
={IFNA(FILTER(x),WRAPROWS(,15,));IFNA(FILTER(y),WRAPROWS(,15,))}
```

Then, you can wrap this in LET (just to name it), and filter counting the values in each row:

```
=LET(filteredrange,{IFNA(FILTER(x),WRAPROWS(,15,));IFNA(FILTER(y),WRAPROWS(,15,))},
FILTER(filteredrange,BYROW(filteredrange,LAMBDA(row,COUNTA(row)>0))))
```

If you know that certain column shouldn't be empty in your filters, you can avoid the BYROW calculations, and just add it as a new condition. For example, if it were column 3:

```
    =LET(filteredrange,{IFNA(FILTER(x),WRAPROWS(,15,));IFNA(FILTER(y),WRAPROWS(,15,))},
FILTER(filteredrange,(INDEX(filteredrange,,3)<>""))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `VSTACK`, like this:

```
=VSTACK(filter(x),filter(y))
```

`VSTACK` will stack the two arrays even if they have incompatible sizes. It will however return an error in the positions that couldn't be stacked, you can get rid of these errors with error handling functions, `FILTER` or `QUERY`.